# How to create an empty table of size with headers in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I would like to create a table of 5 columns and 10000 rows,
such that it has headers with empty cells in the beginning. I will fill in the cells with strings or numbers later after calculation. How to do that?
Thanks.

Jen

Comment: Did you try  `cell(10000,5)`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a way:

Let's say you have the following headers:

```
headers = {'A' 'B' 'C' 'D' 'E'};
```

Then initialize the data (in your case 10 000 x 5, here 4 x 5) as an empty cell. Then convert to a table and edit the `VariableNames` property to make it the headers:

```
data = cell(4,5);
T = cell2table(data);
T.Properties.VariableNames = headers
```

Output:

```
T = 

    A     B     C     D     E 
    __    __    __    __    __

    []    []    []    []    []
    []    []    []    []    []
    []    []    []    []    []
    []    []    []    []    []
```

Comment: Great! You can click the green tickmark at the top left of the answer. Thanks!

Comment: I am not seeing anything green on this page.

Comment: Oh actually it turns green once you click it haha. It's an empty check mark I believe, beside the "score" of the answer (right now there is a big 1)

Comment: Yes. There is a big 1. That is the 1 I clicked.

Comment: thanks! Oh actually it was right below the number haha. Cheers :)